# When did people first start thinking 'C is portable assembler'?

Tags: c

It seems to be an 'accepted concept' in the popular culture of programming languages that 'C is portable assembler'.  I have first heard this at least 15 years ago.  But when did it really become part of the popular culture?

Note: if you don't agree that 'C is portable assembler', please just skip this question.  This question is about 'popular culture of programming'.  I'll add a comment to this question which you can up-vote for those who disagree with that statement.

Comment: I did not know there was popular culture for programming languages to start with.  Does this mean non-programmers-culture?

Comment: Seems weird to posit something is an 'accepted concept' then to take out of the discussion whether or not it actually is or is not an accurate statement.  I actually don't know a single programmer that would agree with that statement.  C is close to the metal sure and portable, but C is very far removed from assembly.

Comment: Remember back when Google Groups would actually let you search Usenet?  I was using the quote "C combines all the power of assembly with all the easy of use of assembly" back in the 1990s.

Comment: @Serapth: that would be because SO is not for discussion...  It is commonly accepted by Haskell, O'Caml, Scala, Mathematica, Maple, even Scheme programmers that C (from their perspective) is essentially indistinguishable from assembly.

Comment: @Paul: Feb 2000 is the earliest that Google Groups will find that quote -- but it does call it "trad".

Comment: @Paul I remember when Google Groups was Deja News and life was good.  I miss deja news.   @Jacques, you have a habit of speaking on behalf of a great many programmers...

Comment: @Paul Since when did Google Groups stop letting you search Usenet? Here's a reference to the aphorism in question from net.jokes in 1986: http://groups.google.com/group/net.jokes/browse_thread/thread/7abe87b3cf66a550/f84fda9d69930425#f84fda9d69930425

Comment: @Serapth: pop-culture ~ zeitgeist ~ impressions of the crowd.  That's different than speaking 'on behalf of'.  And for 4 of those languages, I would take a bet that a poll would indeed find more people from those communities who agree than disagree.

Comment: @Tyler: Google still lets you *search* the newsgroups -- but in a lot of cases, you won't *find* much, even that you know is there. For better or worse, they seem to "fiddle" with things semi-regularly, so sometimes things work nicely, other times poorly, and sometimes not at all.

Comment: Subjective and argumentative on *both* the issue of whether c is or is not "portable assembly" and on what constitutes "accepted wisdom". Nor is there a heck of a lot to be learned here.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but isn't it much more appropriate for programmers.se than here on SO?

Comment: The discussion/voting on this question makes no sense to me. "There is a general impression that <X>" is a far cry from "<X> is God's given truth" or even "I personally believe <X>". And even if <X> is incorrect, it's *still useful* to know how the idea that <X> is true got popularized--in fact, it might be **more** useful than if <X> were actually true!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be about the history of computing in C rather than about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From the Introduction to the first edition of *The C Programming Language*:

> C is a relatively "low level"
>   language. This characterization is not
>   pejorative; it simply means that C
>   deals with the same sort of objects
>   that most computers do, namely
>   characters, numbers, and addresses.

[ ... ]

> Again, because the language reflects the capabilities of current computers, C programs tend to be efficient enough that there is no compulsion to write assembly language instead.

[ ... ]

> Although C matches the capabilities of many computers, it is independent of any particular machine architecture, and so with a little care it is easy to write "portable" programs ...

At least the general idea of combining portability with the general capabilities of assembly language seems to have been there almost from the beginning.

Comment: Considering that it went hand-in-hand with the creation of Unix, it would be surprising if this weren't the case.

Comment: @Mark: OTOH, consider that Modula (the less known predecessor to Modula II) was developed in conjunction with the creation of the Lilith system, but is generally rather higher level.

Comment: @Jerry, that might actually strengthen the case. Is the success of C vs. Modula an accident of history, or did the language designs give Unix an advantage from the start?

Comment: @Mark: I suspect it's at least partly that nobody really cared about Modula being a long-term success. Niklaus Wirth seems to want to ground his languages in reality, but he's always seemed more interested in exploring new things (mostly languages) than in managing and growing existing projects. It was also designed as an integrated system, so it didn't really accommodate other languages, etc., where Unix has always supported multiple languages, development styles, etc.

Comment: Modula and Modula-2 went nowhere not because they're particularly high level languages (they're not much higher than C!) but because they didn't have a quasi-free operating system spreading like a virus to bolster their popularity.  At the time Unix was almost unique in being a semi-capable operating system written in a portable language that wasn't wrapped up in billions of proprietary licensing arrangements (because AT&T didn't notice there was a potential market for it until after the cat had escaped the bag).

Answer (score 13):

That was why C was developed.  From the very, very beginning, C was designed for portability.

Comment: Sure - but was it thought of as a 'very low level' language when it was designed?

Comment: What does "very low level" mean?  Low level by modern standards?  Or low level by the standards of the day?  It's a relative term.  And -- in most cases -- meaningless.

Comment: @Jacques Carette: At the time, it was very high-level, compared to assembly.

Comment: In it's day, it was higher-level than "B".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language) and BCPL.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL

Comment: @rampion: Prolog and LISP long pre-date C.  Those are 'very high-level'.  Even the originators of C (see Jerry Coffin's answer) did not think that C was high-level.

Comment: LISP has functions called "CAR" and "CDR".  Contents of the Address part of Register number and Contents of the Decrement part of Register number.  How is that "high level" when it specifically identifies hardware registers?

Answer (score 6):

The concept of C being "portable assembler" stems for the simple fact that most "pop-culture level" C programmers are too lazy to learn the language "hard" - academic - way, and instead prefer to "learn" from practice, in most part by associating the language commands with the implied underlying machine code. Most of these associations are based on rather ridiculous misconceptions about the language, which latter surface here (and on other forums) as questions along the lines of "I have 20 years of experience in C programming but I don't understand why my type-punning hack no longer works". Nevertheless, most of those "portable assembler" types actually take pride in their approach, considering everybody else not sufficiently competent to see assembly behind the C code :)

In other words, the only people who see C as portable assembler are the people who never bothered to learn the language. It is indeed just a pop-culture. C is not a portable assembler, and it is not really a matter of "agreeing" or "disagreeing" with it, but rather a matter of *knowing* it as a hard fact. The "popular culture of programming" you seem to be mentioning has very little connection with the professional C programming world.

Comment: So why do professional compiler writers frequently target C rather than assembler?  As far as they are concerned, C is 'close enough' to the metal (and gcc is decent enough) so that it's not worth bothering going further down.  [And I used to be a professional C programmer, I just grew tired of having to type so much to say so little.  Of course, Java was worse in that way.  But I'm one of those weird Haskell/O'Caml programmers].

Comment: And see Jerry Coffin's answer.

Comment: "In other words, the only people who see C as portable assembler are the people who never bothered to learn the language."  Weird.  In my experience it's "the only people who *don't* see C as a portable assembler are the people who never bothered to learn **another** language well."  Amazing how perceptions can vary from person to person, no?

Comment: @JUSTMYcorrectOPINION For the sake of providing a counterexample, I do C# professionally, I used to do assembly professionally, and I do C and C++ for fun. I've also done Matlab if you want to throw that in too. I don't think C is portable assembly, and honestly I have no idea how this "C is portable assembly" thing caught on. Assembly is assembly and C is C, and C has features that are way, way higher level than any assembly language would ever be (even given macro enhancements present in MASM, etc.). Also, C is only portable if you put effort into making portable code.

Comment: can you describe what you mean by learning C the "hard" - academic way? I would very much like to have a formal understanding of C, not just know how to use it by practicing it, but don't know exactly what to search for.

Comment: @Александър Гьорев: The authors of the Standard recognized that implementations intended for different purposes should support different useful behaviors, and that it would be impractical for the Standard to define them all.  It thus categorizes certain actions for which implementations may or may not opt to define useful behaviors, at their leisure.  Some people, however, do not view any such extensions as part of the language even though the published Rationale for the C Standard recognizes that such extensions are a bit part of what make the language useful in the first place.

Comment: This the best answer, but there's one point I've got to raise: I think **academic** is probably the wrong word to use. It implies that one should get a PhD in C to be able to understand C. On the other hand, when C is "taught" as part of a higher education, the understanding that students get is exactly on the "pop-culture level", i.e., with faulty concepts of what C is and what the compiler is allowed to do. This is possibly because the professors themselves don't know C properly, and because teaching C is rarely a real goal...

Comment: ... instead the educational goals are: (1) introduction to programming and (2) introduction to how computers can be used on a certain *low* level.

Comment: @user4180854 First, you need to have cppreference and the standards ready to use. The C standard drafts are free to access, while in the case of C++ even the Git repo is available: https://en.cppreference.com/w/ https://github.com/cplusplus/draft Also have your compiler's manual on hand: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/ The exact route you take can depend a great deal on what you are (or will be) interested in - so when you start hacking, be prepared to consult the references I mentioned, and don't be afraid to ask questions on Stack Exchange. I think that there's no ...

Comment: ... clear cut route, but maybe a clear cut route is not even possible. In general, the issues that @AnT and me are alluding to are caused when someone thinks that they can use C (or C++) as a portable assembly language. I.e., they know that something is **possible on their computer architecture**, so they erroneously "translate" this knowledge **to the C level**, when they instead should **just follow the rules of C** while writing C (inline assembly notwithstanding). Examples are type punning, signed integer overflow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the first time that there was a higher level language than C.

That would make C portable, but still fairly low level (and at least in some minds, the closest you can get to Assembler and still be portable).

Comment: Which would make it 'never' since LISP pre-dates C by 2 decades.

Comment: @Jacqeues - Actually, that would make it "since it was introduced".

Comment: @Jacques.  In a sense Lisp is quite low level.  See the etymology of the terms `car` and `cdr` to see why. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR

Answer (score -1):

The moment they started extrapolating/ misinterpreting definitions of words :)

Assembly language: symbolic representation (a.k.a. mnemonics) of the numeric machine codes and other constants needed to program a particular CPU  architecture.

Assembler: A program to convert assembly language into machine language.

C: A programming language which

```
    (1) is not a mnemonic of a particular CPU architecture
    (2) cannot be fed into an assembler
```

P.S:Feel free to downvote this answer as much as you want :)

Comment: While I agree 100% with you, the question was: "When did people first start thinking ‘C is portable assembler’ ?" the "*portable assembler*" phrase itself was an analogy IMHO. A comparison. Not that C *is* an assembly language (and I don't think that the author meant that) but is considered *like* an assembly language. 

My 2cts. And no, I won't downvote a correct answer :)

Comment: I understood what the OP was trying to convey..i was just having some fun,especially since he put the phrase in quotes :P