# What makes a programming language fast?

Tags: compilation

Or worded in a more relevant way, *what characteristics of a programming language influence the fastness of the corresponding generated executable*?

Sure that's the compiler which generate the executable which really matter. You may for example imagine something as advanced as a compilation chain able to infer an executable from a natural language description, asking relevant question with provided suggestions to disambiguate if probability to make a good match with given data is too low.

Now C is famous for enabling developers to get really fast executables, "portable assembler". But is that because the language ease the match between the source and target code, and in the same time, ease the development of optimized compilers? Or is that because the developers using C are more sensitive with how it works under the wood and so code with that in mind? Or some other reason?

[When did people first start thinking 'C is portable assembler'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040276/when-did-people-first-start-thinking-c-is-portable-assembler)

Comment: Most benefit is gained at development time and error prevention. Actual performance is seldom a compiler issue. Inefficiencies are usually due to improper programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C has remains the 'fastest' language because of its flexibility. It doesn't impose a rigid runtime model. Developers are free to create their own runtime structure, architecture, and data structures.

For example, 20 years ago processors were 'slow' (relative to memory speed) and many optimizations focused on looking up results in large tables of precomputed values. Now, processors are fast and memory is slow. Now, optimizations focus on cache efficiency - since large data tables will blow the cache, they are usually avoided and the tasks are shifting back to the processor.

Many languages are much more than just a language. Most modern languages include heavy runtime frameworks and libraries on which the speed depends. These runtime frameworks usually lock in fundamental data structures and memory management models. When hardware changes, inflexible frameworks become inefficient.

Because C compiles predictibly to native object code, and does not impose a heavy runtime, it has, and will continue to handle major hardware architectural changes and will always be among the fastest languages.

Comment: Very good answer. That's the kind I'm looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

less code used for a problem where it took more code to solve in another programming language

Comment: Verbosity don't seems to be the sole parameter, python is far less verbose than C for example, when the latter have a reputation to provide faster executable.

Answer (score 0):

The predominant characteristic that is considered to make a language fast is how well its data types correspond to machine data types.  Java is considered to be an efficient language because it has primitive data types. Conversely, the performance of anything written in any language which treats all types (even chars and ints) as objects, (as all scripting/untyped languages do,) is bound to suffer.

Answer (score 0):

C is fast because there is no language beneath C except Assembly. So this is one reason.

Second, In which language Compiler is written is also matter because if language it self slow then then compiler written in that language is also slow. So, it will produce code but not so fast.

Third, Many time language implementation algorithm also play an important role say how language's datatype is implemented and so on.

Generating optimized code so can it run fast and also take less memory is in NP-Completeness.

Comment: Well, 'no language beneath' is relative to how you compile the code. The language in which the compiler is written is an egg/chicken problem here. My question is more oriented toward 'what features enable easier optimization in a source language?'.

Comment: And i think its important for language as how it compile code say one language X which is converted into C and then into Assembly, so its probably not fast language because it take two conversation in generating code.