# Where does the statement that C is "portable assembly" originate?

Tags: c

When writing C, you are writing code for the C abstract machine, and the C standard gives the compiler enormous leeway in how it translates this code. Yet there is a persistent, commonly stated belief that the C language is a sort of "high-level assembly" or perhaps "portable assembly", with the implication that it is possible to meaningfully predict the kind of machine code that will be generated based on the C source.

Where does this misconception (or perhaps a metaphor gone astray) originate from?

Comment: This is not a misconception... It's true to a very high degree... The amount of cross platform software is sheer proof...

Comment: Also take a look at <stdint.h> this consept is as old as C

Comment: An experienced C developer can absolutely predict the generated machine code.

Comment: The question seems misplaced. It is not a programming problem.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart OK, without looking... what will `return argc % 9;` generate? (with `-O3`)

Comment: @whitequark "the C abstract machine" was something introduced by the first C standard (1989). I think the term you're asking about comes from the 1970s . many things from that era stick around despite being nonsense, e.g. casting malloc

Comment: @AK_: `stdint.h` came with C99. Earlier versions had to use their own zoo of machine-types or did rely on the standard types to have a specific size (which is one reason Windows64  still has 32 bit `long`.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: an experienced C developper can predict the machine code an inexperienced compiler would produce, more or less.  But modern compilers apply many tricks most of which escape most experienced programmers.  Try this site to test your prediction skills: http://gcc.godbolt.org/#

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040276/when-did-people-first-start-thinking-c-is-portable-assembler

Comment: @AK_ The quantity of software broken by C compiler improvements is proof to the contrary.

Comment: @chqrlie aha, thanks!

Comment: Well... C is the closest thing to a cross platform assembler... And conditional compilation, and macros, help mitigate what different compilers do... Though they can definitely create a bigger headache....

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: Absolutely!  But you are among the few who can prove that 99.9% of C software are riddled with subtile and not so subtile bugs.